# How to get mouseposition (pageX , pageY) during mousemove with pressed mousebutton

Tags: jquery

I need the actual mouseposition of every move only when the mousebutton is pressed.

I used the following:

```
var time, click= $( '#foo li' );
    click.mousedown(function(e){
                time= setInterval(function(){
                    $( '#foo li' ).mousemove(function( event ) {
                        var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
                        msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
                        $( ".output" ).empty();
                        $( ".output' ).append( msg );
                    });
            }, 500);
            return false;
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(e){
            clearInterval(time);
            $(window).unbind( 'mousemove');
            return false;
        });
```

It works fine: every position will be printed in 'output'. But the mouseup Event will not stop the mousemove function. What could be the problem?

**Update:**

Sorry,im just beginner...

I tried it this way and it works fine. Is there a better way to do this so tell me...

```
var down = false;
$('#foo').mousedown(function(){
    down = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    down = false;
})

$('#foo').mousemove(function(e){
    if(down == false) return;
      $('.output').empty();
      $('.output').append(e.pageX +' & ' + e.pageY);
});
```

Comment: Store in a var whether or not the mousebtn is down and only output then while mousemove

Comment: Many things are bad in your code. You bind mousemove event to `$( '#foo li' )` on each interval tick and then try to unbind some mousemove event bound to `window` while what you want is to unbind mousemove event bound to these LIs. Your logic is clearly failing...

Comment: The mousemove event always happen on every pixel's movement. You don't need to set a time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var click= $( '#foo li' );
click.mousedown(function(e){
  $( '#foo li' ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
    msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
    $( '.output' ).empty();
    $( '.output' ).append( msg );
  });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  $( '#foo li' ).unbind( 'mousemove');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output"></div>
<div id="foo">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</div>
```